# Website Footer is Overlapping Page Content on Smaller Screens

Tags: html, css, overlapping

[Our company website](http://www.bradfordlicensing.com) looks fine on a large screen size where it was originally designed (1920x1080 21.5" screen); however when it is viewed on a smaller screen size (i.e. 15" laptop or mobile), the footer overlaps the content to fit to the bottom of the browser window.

I followed a sticky footer tutorial and it doesn't seem to be working. There is also extra white space underneath the footer which is causing a `y-scrollbar` to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use position:absolute; for the content. use position:relative; instead

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body
{
    height: 99%;
    background-color:Black;
}
.header
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 15%;
    background-color:Gray;
}
#Content
{
    min-height: 85%;
    width: 960px;
    background-color:Navy;
}
.con
{
    min-height:900px;
    width:960px;
    background-color:Aqua;
}
```

and

```
   <div class="header">
   </div>
   <div id="Content">
   <div class="con"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="header">
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I change the positioning from absolute to relative on the logo and topnav divs, all of the alignment gets thrown off on the whole site though.